# What's the source of this verse (yuktiyuktaṃ vaco grāhyaṃ bālād api śukād api)?

Tags: identification-request, sanskrit, shloka

> yuktiyuktaṃ vaco grāhyaṃ bālād api śukād api 
>   yukti hīnam, vacas tyājyaṃ vṛddhād api śukād api
>
> ---
>
> Whatever is based on sound reasoning ought to be accepted, even if it proceeds from a boy or parrot. Whatever is not so based ought to be rejected, even if it is uttered by an old man or the sage Śuka himself.

Source: [Religion and Society by Sarvepalli Radhakrishnan](https://archive.org/stream/religionandsocie035173mbp#page/n117/mode/1up/search/boy+or+a+parrot)

Comment: Seems like a [Sanskrit Subhasita](http://mcjoshi21.blogspot.com/2014/05/todays-subhashita_28.html)

Comment: Looks like there is also a similar verse also with   the name of Bṛhaspati (Guru of the Gods). युक्तियुक्तं वचो ग्राह्यं बालादपि शुकादपि ।

अयुक्तमपि न ग्राह्यं साक्षादपि बृहस्पतेः ॥

Comment: युक्तिहीनविचारेण धर्महानिः प्रजायते, but अचिन्त्या खलु ये भावा मा तांस्तर्केण योजयेत्. So role of logic is both accepted but not everywhere

Comment: Similar verse is there in yoga vasitha!

Answer (score 4):

We can find a similar verse from Yoga Vasistha.
i.e

> युक्तियुक्तमुपादेयं वचनं बालकादपि ।
>  अन्यत्तृणमिव त्याज्यमप्युक्तं
> पद्मजन्मना ॥ ३ ॥
>
> yuktiyuktamupādeyaṃ vacanaṃ bālakādapi | 
> anyattṛṇamiva tyājyamapyuktaṃ
> padmajanmanā || 3 ||
>
> > Words conformable with reason are to be received even if spoken by
> > boys; otherwise, they are to be rejected as straws though pronounced
> > by the lotus-born.
>
> Source - Yoga Vasitha [[2.18.3]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-sanskrit/d/doc249996.html)

Comment: Hi, I have edited your answer to support better formatting with block quotes. Feel free to roll back the edit, if you don't agree with it. Thanks!

Comment: @Vivikta thanks.